# How can I make AGC on by default?

Tags: windows-10, audio, control-panel

There is an option in control panel-->sound-->record devices, named AGC (Automatic Gain Control).
AGC is helpful for me to improve audio quality. Without it, I need to be close to my microphone.
The problem is that every time I restart my computer, this setting always resets to OFF (unchecked), so I need to set it after each boot. This is really annoying.

I use Windows 10 64bit with Realtech HD audio driver.

What can I do to make ACG on by default after each boot?

Comment: same problem here. @InBug Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Where do you have the AGC setting? I want to turn it off on my PC but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

- Goto ***Control panel***
- Open ***Sound***
- Click on ***Recording*** tab!
  [image: recording tab]
- select your mic and click the ***properties*** button on the bottom.
- Set your mic's ***ACG*** to enable
  [image]
- Uncheck the ***Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device***